# Heroku not deploying CSS or Sass in Rails 4.2.4 app even though "config.assets.compile = true" in config/environments/production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I've been having this issue for a while now. When I deploy my app, I get the HTML but no CSS or Sass.

It looks like the most common solution for this is setting config.assets.compile in config/environments/production.rb to "true", then recommitting changes and deploying again. I've tried many variations on this but nothing seems to work (e.g. https://www.natashatherobot.com/rails-4-heroku-assets-not-found-css-image/)

Note: After every change I've tried, I've committed to Git and pushed to Heroku, so I know that's not the issue either.

Update: After a quick test, it turns out that Heroku is taking CSS, but only from application.css.scss, but almost all of my CSS is in custom.css.scss, so I need to find out why Heroku is only taking form application.css.scss and no other style sheets.

Comment: `config.assets.compile` should be **false**, not true, if you're precompiling assets.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm trying it with *false* as well and it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. The pre-compile fix that you found was definitely an issue with Rails 3 and may still be. [Heroku has a totally different set of instructions for Rails 4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline).

They suggest setting this:

```
#config/application.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

**OR**, if you're looking for something even simpler, you can throw this gem into the mix:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I already have rails_12factor as a production gem. Do you think the combination of having all those things set to "true" in the production.rb and having the rails_12factor gem might be causing this issue?

Comment: Yeah, that's very likely. Unless you have a specific reason for altering the default production config you should probably just leave it alone. Rails is doing a lot of really nice things for you, but it is easy to get them out of concert if you start changing a bunch of them. Hence the need for the Gem.